# Vue reactive data showing as Observer and not actual value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, reactive

I have some methods in a component:

```
  created() {
    return this.getConversation(this.$route.params.ConversationId).then(
      respConversation => {
        this.conversation = respConversation;
      }
    );
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.conversation);
    return this.getConversationTranscripts(this.conversation.AudioId);
  },
```

However, `this.conversation` prints as `{__ob__: Observer}` and doesn't have `AudioId`

Both `this.getConversation` and `this.getConversationTranscripts` return promises.

Comment: Promises are asynchronous, so `mounted` will be called before the `then`. Returning Promises from `created` and `mounted` won't make any difference, they will still happen without waiting for the Promises to complete.

Comment: So then how do I make sure that the `mounted` has the data it needs?

Comment: You can't. If you need data to be present for this component to function correctly then you'd need to move responsibility for loading that data to the parent and not create this component until that data is available. If you want to keep responsibility in this component then it'll just have to deal with waiting for that data to arrive. If possible you'd have the call to `getConversationTranscripts` inside the `then`. I would also note that `mounted` is called after the component is rendered, so if you need the data for rendering you might want to use `beforeMount` or `created` instead.

Comment: Please add as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning Promises from Vue's lifecycle hooks doesn't do much. It certainly doesn't make them wait for the Promise to complete. The same would be true using `async`/`await`.

Internally the hooks are called using `callHook`, e.g. `callHook(vm, 'mounted')`. You can see the code for `callHook` at:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/b7c2d9366cf731a1551286b8ac712e6e0905070e/src/core/instance/lifecycle.js#L336

This calls out to `invokeWithErrorHandling`, which you can see at:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/b7c2d9366cf731a1551286b8ac712e6e0905070e/src/core/util/error.js#L36

While `invokeWithErrorHandling` does have some minimal support for handling any Promises that are returned, those Promises are ignored by `callHook`.

In the code shown in the question the `created` hook will be called followed by the `mounted` hook. The `then` on the `getConversation` Promise won't be called until later as that will be asynchronous.

So at the point `mounted` is called the value of `this.conversation` will still be its initial value, presumably an empty object. Vue's reactivity system will cause that to be shown as `{__ob__: Observer}` in the console.

If the component needs that data to be able to function then the parent will have to take responsibility for loading that data and delay creating the component until the data is available.

More likely the component will just need to cope with the data being missing when it's first rendered. It will then need to chain together the asynchronous calls using Promises:

```js
created() {
  this.getConversation(this.$route.params.ConversationId).then(
    respConversation => {
      this.conversation = respConversation;
      this.getConversationTranscripts(this.conversation.AudioId);
    }
  );
}
```

Using `async`/`await` is maybe a little cleaner here:

```js
async created() {
  this.conversation = await this.getConversation(this.$route.params.ConversationId)
  this.getConversationTranscripts(this.conversation.AudioId);
}
```

None of this will pause the component's lifecycle, so rendering will continue with `this.conversation` still set to its initial value and the template will have to be coded to deal with that.

I would add that using `this.$route.params.ConversationId` is not ideal. If possible this would be injected via a prop instead. You'll also need to be very careful when this value changes. If the value changing causes a new component to be created then no problem but if it just updates the existing component you could run into problems. The `created` and `mounted` hooks only run once, when the component is first created, so reusing the same component when the params change won't run them again.

Comment: Awesome. Very helpful answer. The component will be recreated if the Params change. I’m trying to make each component as independent as possible - relying on globally available information when possible